# If $g(x) = f(\sin(2x))$ and $g'(0) = 1$ then what is $f'(0)$?

Tags: derivatives

If $g(x) = f(\sin(2x))$ and $g'(0) = 1$ then what is $f'(0)$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109707/discussion-on-question-by-omidh-if-gx-f-sin2x-and-g0-1-then-wha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since g is differentiable at $0$
By the chain rule $$ g’(0)= f’(0) 2 cos(0)=1$$ Rearranging we get $f’(0)=1/2$